# Azure devops issue with sonar cloud code coverage

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In azure devops build pipeline, I am having the below stages.

- Prepare analysis on sonar cloud
- dotnet restore
- dotnet build
- dotnet test
- dontnet publish
- copy test files .. this for copying (*.trx *.xml) to respective directory.
- Run code analysis
- Publish quality gate result.

here my pipeline runs successfully with the tests but its not giving code coverage. code coverage showing 0.00%

*.trx file is copying on the required path & I have also tried with the default path of trx file but its giving below message in logs.

#### ERROR MESSAGE

```
Post-processing started.
00:23:49.775  Property 'sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths' provided, skipping the search for TRX files in default folders.
00:23:49.995  Did not find any binary coverage files in the expected location.
00:23:49.995  Falling back on locating coverage files in the agent temp directory.
00:23:49.995  Searching for coverage files in D:\a\_temp
00:23:49.995  No coverage files found in the agent temp directory.
WARNING: The following projects do not have a valid ProjectGuid and were 
not built using a valid solution (.sln) thus will be skipped from 
analysis...
D:\a\1\s\Rost.API.Tests\Rost.API.Tests.csproj
```

I expect the code coverage in the pipeline, currently code coverage showing 0.00%.

Answer (score 2):

May i confirm several questions with you?

1. Did you add `--collect "Code coverage"` option to the command line arguments?
   [image]

> Code coverage can be collected by adding --collect "Code coverage"
>   option to the command line arguments. This is currently only available
>   on the Windows platform.

2. If run the test command on local, did the code coverage show correctly?

BTW, SonarQube requires a valid Project GUID but Core projects dont actually use this.It is recommended to add the ProjectGUID in the test project file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <!-- SonarQube requires a valid Project GUID but Core projects dont actually use this -->
    <ProjectGuid>{9C99E491-F56E-4515-9F0B-D72A5207DB13}</ProjectGuid>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Lu Muke we added Microsoft.NET.Sdk & its start working.